# airport transit visa for cairo

Tags: visas, egypt

i am an Egyptian national traveling from Doha-Istanbul then Istanbul-Rome then Rome-Paris finally Paris- Cairo. Do i need airport transit visa to change flights in Rome and Paris. I will not leave the airports just changing flights as my final destination is Cairo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a rather circuitous route.

This itinerary has two stops inside the Schengen zone: one in Rome and another in Paris. For immigration purposes, the flight from Rome to Paris is treated as a "domestic" flight. You will need to go through immigration to enter the Schengen area in Rome, then go through exit immigration to leave the area in Paris.

Accordingly, you will not just need an airport transit visa for this trip; you'll need a full Schengen visa.

Comment: What if i will transit only in Rome and then Cairo So the new route will be Doha-Istanbul   ...... Istanbul - Rome     Rome-Cairo Do i need a transit visa?

Comment: @Murad See [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area) for all the conditions that apply. Such a trip would be possible without a transit visa if you can remain airside (without going through immigration) and meet all the conditions for transit without visa.